# Where do I go for support on a new stack exchange site?

Tags: support, beta-phase, help

I committed to a Stack Exchange site that is now in private beta.  However, the beta will not let me in (probably because I didn't not get my openId associated with the account that committed until after the beta started).

That all said, the site says for me to email team@stackexchange.com if I have problems. Emails to this account are bouncing as "unknown user."  Is the help page wrong?

Comment: Posting here is a good option, you'll get an answer soon

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson: stack**e**overflow??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually use:

```
team@stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: team@stackexchange.com really ought to work though.